# How to run mysql_upgrade when using xampp?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, xampp, mariadb, bitnami

Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, unity, latest version of xampp. How to run

`mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

I tried running it in home directory and `/opt/lampp/bin` and `/opt/lampp/`, nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if you follow this steps:

1. Go to the xampp directory: cd /opt/lampp/
2. Go to the bin directory: cd bin
3. Execute the script: ./mysql_upgrade